# Auto insurance for visitors? (Washington state, US)

Tags: usa, automobiles, insurance, washington-state

If I have a visitor from abroad, do I need to add them on my auto insurance policy temporarily for them to be able to drive in Washington state?

I'll double check with the insurer, but I would like to also know about other people's experience doing it.

Comment: It can depend on many factors, particularly how long they are staying with you.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add them fairly easily to your policy.  Though it may depend on your insurer.

I was able to do this through 21st Century insurance (in Pennsylvania but I don't think this would be an issue anywhere else), the requirement was presentation of their driver's licenses and the IDP (International Driver's Permit) as well as copies of the passports.  After that there was no issue.